# Why after selecting the location it is again asking for select location in JS dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!--html part-->
```

/*I have implemented autocomplete search bar for my web site.onclick of dropdown button my input text field will appear in that i can enter my location 
after entering the location further process will takes place.in the input text field my selected location takes normally but in the dropdown button is showing again same "select location"
     
            
             Select Location
            
    toggle shows same as select location after selecting the location

```
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          <!--AutoComplete Search bar-->
    $(function() {
        $("#locName").autocomplete({
            source: [
                "Adugodi",

                "Yelahanka"

            ],
            minLength: 1,
            function(event) {
                var value = event.getAttribute('value')
                var locName = document.getElementById("locName").value;
                if (value.includes('&')) {
                    value = value.replace("&", "%26");
                }
                if (locName == "") {
                    alert("Please Select your Location");
                } else {
                    window.location = "http://Example.com?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
    });

        <!--Auto Complete For Categories-->
        function Demo(anchor) {
            var value = anchor.getAttribute('value')
            var locName=document.getElementById("locName").value;
            if(value.includes('&')){
                value = value.replace("&", "%26");
            }
           if(locName==""){
               alert("Please Select your Location");
           }
            else
                {
                     window.location = "http://Example.com?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is like white space or string comparision.....
try like this

```html
if(locName.trim()===""){//trim()-for remove white space and'===' for string comparision
alert("Please Select your Location");
}
else
{
window.location = "http://Example.com?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pols i have problem in dropdown button..after entering the location in input text field.my drop down button should reflect the location name which i have entered in the input text field

Comment: where is the dropdown button?

Comment: <div class="dropdown" style=margin-left:200px;margin-top:-40px>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_coins" data-toggle="dropdown" >
     Select Location
    </button>
    <div  class="dropdown-menu" style=margin-top:20px;margin-left:415px>
        <form class="px-0 py-0">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" id='locName' placeholder="Enter Location & Search" >
        </form>

Comment: Can anybody help me out of this